# Is the phrase "Whatever makes you happy" passive aggressive?

Tags: phrases

I want a more confident grasp of this phrase/sentence.

Was playing a game. Text exchange between me (a man) and a woman. After some things said, me- I'm smarter than you. her- whatever makes you happy with yourself.

I said this being half playful (although not wanting anything from her) and half honest in a friendly way (honest opinion from previous experiences about her).

I just want to be sure: this phrase in such contexts (not literal) means a passive aggressive attack, right?

(BTW, not fun, smart, confident kind of woman from this response)

Answer (score 2):

In the context, I would understand it as "Believe anything you want, if it makes you happy".  In particular, you said, "I'm smarter than you" (which is at best "banter" and at worse an insult). Her response was a put-down:

> If believing that you are smarter than me makes you happy, then I won't argue with you, but I know it's not true.

There is a lot of subtext here. The meaning isn't in the words, but in my reading of the relationship and the wider context.

Without more context about the relationship, I would not judge this to be "passive-aggressive".  At least it is no more passive-aggressive than the phrase "I'm smarter than you" is aggressive.  If it were part of a pattern of behaviour I might change my mind.  However, you were rude first.

Comment: Sad snowflake ***